# Book Request: Differential Geometry and Particle Physics

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I've been studying differential geometry for about a year (books I've read include *An Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* and *Riemannian Manifolds: An Introduction to Curvature* by Lee, and sections of *Geometry of Physics* by Frankel).  I really enjoy reading pages that go into detail about differential geometric aspects, such as [gauge theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroweak_interaction) (Lie groups) or the [Aharanov-Bohm Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect#Mathematical_interpretation) (flat connections over Lie groups).

Can anyone recommend books that discuss topics, such as particle physics, from a rigorous differential geometric/mathematical physics perspective? Bonus if it touches on the history of the deveoplment of the theory.

Answer (score 1):

You can read " Modern Differential Geometry in Gauge Theories" by Anastasios Mallios.